# use autoaudiosink in pipeline and play media without sound

Tags: gstreamer

I'd like to use pipeline below to play content with sound and without sound. Problem is that content without sound PREROLLING pipeline, but doesn't play

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe uridecodebin uri=file:///home/mymediafile.ogv name=d1 ! tee name=t1 ! queue max-size-buffers=2 ! jpegenc ! appsink name=myappsink t1. ! queue ! autovideosink d1. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

How can I solve such issue?

Comment: Is your goal to take any generic URL, pass the video as JPEG encoded data to an appsink, and play the audio if it exists?

Comment: Also, are you writing this as an application or from the command line?

Comment: 1. Yes, this is what I'm trying to achieve. I want to pass generic URL to the pipeline, play video and audio if exists. Additionally I want to capture frames in the same time by appsink
2. I'm writting an application. Command line above was only to show how to reproduce my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found no way to get your pipeline going on the command line.  If I put in the audio portion of the pipeline, the files with no audio hang.

In your application however, you'll be able to add a signal for the pad_added events, and only added the audio portion of the pipeline when needed.  Some pseudo code:

```
void decodebin_pad_added(GstElement *decodebin, GstPad *new_pad, gpointer user_data) {
 GstElement* pipeline = (GstElement*)user_data;

 GstCaps* audio_caps = gst_caps_from_string("audio/x-raw");
 GstCaps* pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);
 if(! gst_caps_can_intersect(pad_caps, audio_caps)) {
  return;
 }

 GstElement* audio_pipeline = gst_parse_launch("queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink", NULL);

 gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), audio_pipeline);

 GstElement* decodebin = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "d1");
 gst_element_link(decodebin, audio_pipeline);
 gst_object_unref(decodebin);
}

void decodebin_no_more_pads(GstElement *decodebin, gpointer user_data) {
    GstElement* pipeline = (GstElement*)user_data;

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_PLAYING);
}

GstElement* pipeline = gst_parse_launch("uridecodebin uri=file:///home/mymediafile.ogv name=d1 ! tee name=t1 ! queue max-size-buffers=2 ! jpegenc ! appsink name=myappsink t1. ! queue ! autovideosink", NULL);

GstElement* decodebin = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "d1");
g_signal_connect(decodebin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(decodebin_pad_added), pipeline);
g_signal_connect(decodebin, "no-more-pads", G_CALLBACK(decodebin_no_more_pads), pipeline);

gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED); //pause to make demuxer and decoders get setup and find out what's in the file
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `async-handling=true` to the autoaudiosink.

> gst-launch-1.0.exe uridecodebin uri=file:///home/mymediafile.ogv
>   name=d1 ! tee name=t1 ! queue max-size-buffers=2 ! jpegenc ! appsink
>   name=myappsink t1. ! queue ! autovideosink d1. ! queue ! audioconvert
>   ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink async-handling=true